# Power spectrum of a signal reaches its peak near the zero frequency after detrending the signal

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram, wavelet

I am currently calculating the power spectrum of a signal convolved with a tone burst signal (central frequency = 50 kHz). The sampling rate is 30 MHz and the number of sampling points is 30000. The signal after being convolved is shown in the first figure. However, as shown in the second figure the calculated power spectrum reaches its peak near the zero frequency (rather than the 50 kHz as supposed). Please note that only the frequency from 0 to 500 kHz is considered here for the sake of simplicity. Extra detrending (by subtracting the mean) has been implemented on the convolved signal but the results did not change. I wonder why this happens and how to calculate the power spectrum right so that the calculated power spectrum reaches its peak at the 50 kHz. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. In addition, my codes to calculate the power spectrum are shown as follows.

[image]

[image]

```
fsig = 50e3
N = 3e4
for i in range(1):
    sampling_rate = 30e6
    data = df0.iloc[:, i] - np.mean(df0.iloc[:, i])
    fourier_transform = np.fft.rfft(data)
    abs_fourier_transform = np.abs(fourier_transform)
    power_spectrum = np.square(abs_fourier_transform)
    frequency = np.linspace(0, sampling_rate / 2, len(power_spectrum))
    frequency /= 1e3
    power_spectrum = (power_spectrum - np.min(power_spectrum)) / (np.max(power_spectrum) - np.min(power_spectrum))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(frequency, power_spectrum)
    ax.set_xlim([0, 500])
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [kHz]')
    plt.ylabel('Normalised amplitude')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your first figure doesn't look like a signal convolved with a tone burst.  It looks like a signal multiplied by/modulating a tone burst.

Comment: Also, by eye, the dominant frequency in fig 1 looks to be about 27Khz (wavelength 1100 samples), which is just about where your spectrum plot says it is.  It's definitely not 50Khz (wavelength 600 samples)

Comment: I am new to this area. In this case I implemented Fourier transforms and inverse Fourier transforms to calculate the convolution between the raw chirp signal and a tone burst signal. May I ask why you say that the signal in fig 1 seems not processed via the convolution? Is there anything further that I need to know during the calculation?

Comment: The signal is a chirp?  *Maybe* that could produce the result you show.  It looks like a complex low frequency signal modulating a carrier, but there's more than one way to get a result.  Normally I'd expect a chirp convolved with a tone burst to look like a longer tone burst.  You should mostly be concerned that the dominant frequency is not what you think it should be, though.  I can't guess at what might be wrong with the way you generated the signal, since you didn't include that code.